# message.channel.id Discord PY

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am attempting to make a logging bot however I am having issues with message.channel.id

What is sent upon event being triggered;
Message ID - Message ID | User - User ID | Their Message | My private log channel - Server where they sent message

Intended application of the code;
Message ID - Message ID | User - User ID | Their Message | Server where they sent the message - Server where they sent message

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.author
    user_id = message.author.id
    message_id = message.id
    content = message.content
    channel = message.channel.id
    guild = message.guild
    if user.bot:
        return
    channel = bot.get_channel(my private log channel)
    await channel.send(f"Message ID - {message_id} **|** {user} - {user_id} **|** {content} **|** #{channel} - {guild}")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used twice the same variable `channel`

just rename ones of them

---

Here is an example of a change of the 2 lines:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.author
    user_id = message.author.id
    message_id = message.id
    content = message.content
    message_channel = message.channel.id
    guild = message.guild
    if user.bot:
        return
    channel = bot.get_channel(my private log channel)
    await channel.send(f"Message ID - {message_id} **|** {user} - {user_id} **|** {content} **|** #{message_channel} - {guild}")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```