# how to check if message is in a specific server (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

command I tried:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.server.id == '783763061907527':
         if message.content.startswith('!test'):
               await message.channel.send('this is a test')
```

why it isn't working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64472585/message-channel-id-discord-py - Is this helping you?

Comment: What do you expect? What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`server` was renamed to `guild` in discord.py 1.0+. Also IDs are integers, not strings.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild.id == 783763061907527:
         if message.content.startswith('!test'):
               await message.channel.send('this is a test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Guild, Channel, Message or User's id is an integer. And `startswith` is a function and using like in below.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild.id == 783763061907527:
         if message.content.startswith('!test'):
             await message.channel.send('this is a test')
```